# Openldap Replication don't run after configuring

Tags: replication, ldap, openldap

I'm practicing OpenLDAP replication with 2 Centos 6.9 64bit virtual machines.

The setting-up process was fine, but after I insert data into the master server, nothing happens in the slave.

**MASTER SETTING**

*slapd.conf*

```
overlay syncprov
syncprov-checkpoint 100 10
syncprov-sessionlog 100
updatedn "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
updateref ldap://192.168.1.11:389
```

**SLAVE SETTING**

*slapd.conf*

```
   syncrepl     rid=2
                provider=ldap://192.168.1.10
                type=refreshOnly
                interval=00:00:00:01
                searchbase="dc=example,dc=com"
                filter="(objectClass=*)"
                attrs="*"
                scope=sub
                schemachecking=off
                updatedn="cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com"
                bindmethod=simple
                binddn="cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com"
                credentials=secret
updateref       ldap://192.168.1.10
```

I'm using OpenLDAP 2.4.21,  BerkeleyDB-4.8.

Answer (score 1):

The directives *updatedn* and *updateref* do not make sense at the provider (master).

You probably also want `type=refreshAndPersist` for continous replication. Setting `interval=` to one second would not work well with many entries in the DB.

Make sure that attributes *entryUUID* and *entryCSN* are indexed at the provider.

Also note that OpenLDAP 2.4.21 is really ancient release. During the last 9 years many things were fixed in OpenLDAP, especially related to replication.

I'd recommend to use the RPMs built by [LDAP Toolbox project](https://www.ltb-project.org/documentation/openldap-rpm#yum_repository). They provide YUM repos also for RHEL/CentOS 6.

See also: [OpenLDAP Admin Guide -- Replication](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html)